# How can I fill in a cell based on the value in other rows of that column within the same subset of another variable?

Tags: r, na

How can I, within a given Variable A, translate the non-NA values of Variable B into the cells with a shared in that column with NA while preserving the NAs in Variable C?

|  | Variable A | Variable B | Variable C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | Joe | 1.4 |
| 2 | X | NA | NA |
| 3 | Y | Jane | 1.3 |
| 4 | Y | NA | NA |
| 5 | Y | NA | NA |
| 6 | Z | NA | NA |
| 7 | Z | Fran | 1.7 |
| 8 | Z | NA | NA |
| 9 | Z | NA | NA |

I got into this situation by using the complete() function to create all possible combination of Variable A with another variable that I did not include that above for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Can you show expected?  Do you want `df1 %>% group_by(VariableA) %>% fill(VariableB) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, maybe this:

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>%
   group_by(VarA) %>%
   fill(c(VarB,VarC), .direction = "updown")
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   VarA [3]
  VarA  VarB   VarC
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 X     Joe     1.4
2 X     Joe     1.4
3 Y     Jane    1.3
4 Y     Jane    1.3
5 Y     Jane    1.3
6 Z     Fran    1.6
7 Z     Fran    1.6
8 Z     Fran    1.6
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  VarA = c("X","X","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z"),
  VarB = c("Joe",NA,"Jane",NA,NA,NA,"Fran",NA),
  VarC = c(1.4,NA,1.3,NA,NA,NA,1.6,NA)
)
```